# Class method as function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to pass some class method to some function and take "function call missing argument list; use '&   ' to create a pointer to member" error.

```
//There is some class
class A {
  int someField;
  void Add(int someAdd) {
    someField += someAdd;
  }
}

//And function
void someFunc(std::function<void(int x)> handler) {
  //Some code
  handler(234);
}

//Class method pass to function
void main() {
  A* instanceA = new A();
  someFunc(instanceA->Add); //Error 19  error C3867: 'A::Add': function call missing argument list; use '&A::Add' to create a pointer to member
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Please note that `void main` is wrong, `main`’s return type must be `int`.

Comment: what to do if Add take many parameters (for example 3, 4)?

Answer (score 10):

C++ doesn't have bound methods as a language construct.  Write:

```
someFunc(std::bind(&A::Add, instanceA, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Comment: error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional on line _VARIADIC_EXPAND_0X(_CLASS_BIND, , , , )

Comment: @Vovanok you need to add `std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3`, etc.

Comment: wow ... just have to say this: crazy shit. C++ sometimes freaks me out. Thanks for both question and answer

Comment: I wasted some time until I figured out that, e.g., 3 parameters require the following call: "std::bind(&A::Add, instanceA, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2,std::placeholders::_3)".

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) with place holder as you pass in parameter later:

```
#include <functional>
someFunc(std::bind(&A::Add, instanceA, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Also note, you need to make `A::Add` public

```
class A {    
  int someField;

public:
  void Add(int someAdd) {
    someField += someAdd;
  }
};
```

Also note, in C++ standard no `void main`

```
int main() 
{
    someFunc(std::bind(&A::Add, instanceA, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

Comment: error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional on line _VARIADIC_EXPAND_0X(_CLASS_BIND, , , , )

Comment: maybe your bind isn't correct? it works perfectly fine on my pc

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `std::bind` stuff in the other answers i'd like to propose the usage of lambdas, since those are imo much more readable:

```
int main() {
  A* instanceA = new A();
  someFunc([=](int a1, int a2)
  {
    instanceA->Add(a1, a2);
  }); 
}
```

I know, it will get lengthy if Add takes four, five,... "BigN" parameters, because you have to repeat them all in the lambda's parameter list, but of course you know how to write clean code and don't provide `Add` with "BigN" parameters ;-)

Comment: To my eye, the lambda is less readable.  The extra level of indirection ("call this lambda, which calls this method") makes me look for what else is going on.  Meanwhile, the std::bind is very clearly just looking for a way to execute the method.  Having said that, it's always good to see different takes on the problem and have different options available.  +1 for that.